# How do I create a new application launcher in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, activities-overview

I have a shell script (studio.sh that launches Android Studio) and a png icon.

How do I use these to create a new application launcher icon for Ubuntu 22.04 such that it will show up in "Show applications" menu, and searches in the "Activities" search bar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

1. Create a text file with a `.desktop` extension in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory, for example `~/.local/share/applications/studio.desktop`
2. Include at least the following lines, which tell the desktop how to launch the application.

   ```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=Android Studio
    Exec=studio.sh
    Type=Application
    Icon=studio
   ```

   - This assumes that the executable, `studio.sh`, exists somewhere in your search path, e.g. in `~/.local/bin` or in `./bin`. Else, provide the full pathname to the executable script, e.g. `Exec=/home/user/path/to/studio.sh`.
   - This assumes that the icon is called `studio.png` *and* that the icon is in a standard place, e.g. `~/.local/share/studio.png`. Else, provide the full pathname to the icon file, e.g. `Icon=/home/user/path/to/studio.png`.
   - If the script does not launch a graphical application, but instead should run in a terminal emulator, include a line `Terminal=true`.

A valid `.desktop` file in a valid location, with a valid command on the `exec=` line will automatically, within seconds, appear in your menu system and be searchable.

More fields are available. Study some files under `/usr/share/applications` to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is really useful. I have a follow up question; after locating the application via Activities search bar, once I open it, it appears on the sidebar launcher, but how can I add to the favorites so that it remains in the sidebar? When I right click that app, I don't see add to favorites.