# I want to make a link (unsure what it is called in ubuntu terms) that when I double click on it, it will open a program using WINE. How do I do so?

Tags: wine, 22.04

Just as the title says, I would like to create a link, shortcut, or something of the like that would open a program using the wine command without having to open terminal every time I want to run it. I need a tutorial for this, and hopefully a super basic one so I don't frick anything up.

Comment: you will want to create a .desktop file (in which you can put the exact command you type every time).

Comment: How would I create the .desktop file? I'm sorry, I'm new to creating things on Linux, I've just installed WINE last night, and have used Windows as my daily driver for the past 12 years.

Comment: I don't know all the steps offhand, but that's definitely enough to google for a tutorial. The "link" you're looking for is called a .desktop file, and it provides a clickable icon that runs a pre-specified command when you click it.

Comment: Step #1: How to start a Windows application using Wine: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine#To_start.2Frun_Windows_programs_using_Wine. This will show you how to craft the correct command. Test it a couple times so you know it's correct before moving to Step #2.

Comment: Step #2: How to create/use a .desktop file to create a desktop application launcher: https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop. Put the correct command in your shiny new .desktop file.

Comment: This is giving me a headache. Information overload.

Comment: @user535733 Please just tell me directly what to do. My noodle-brain can't take the information and parse it into what the hell I need to type in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link to .exe doesn't launch Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541317/link-to-exe-doesnt-launch-wine)

Comment: See some basic generic instructions for creating a launcher here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428517/how-do-i-create-a-new-application-launcher-in-ubuntu-22-04. You could also install and use either "Menulibre" or "Alacarte" for creating a menu item.

Comment: I. Don't. Know. What. To. Do. I'm a fricking idiot and need step by step instructions on how to do this PLEASE. ONE person to give me STEP BY STEP what I need to do.